# How can I get this command to check for messages sent globally not only in one channel

Tags: discord, discord.py

I've been trying to get this command to check for all the messages sent by the user in the whole server for ages. I came up with a command that checks for the messages sent by a user in 1 channel only.

```
@client.command(aliases=["m"])
async def messages(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    counter = 0
    async for message in channel.history():
        if message.author == user:
            counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that no matter how you do this, if you're using the ENTIRE server history, it will take some time for the bot to go through it all. With that being known, if this is something you still wish to proceed with here is a solution.

```py
@client.command(aliases=["m"])
async def messages(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    counter = 0
    for channel in guild.channels:
        if isinstance(channel, discord.TextChannel):
            async for message in channel.history(limit=None):
                if message.author.id == user.id:
                    counter += 1
```

Also note I'm comparing IDs instead of the member object itself, this is because that object *can* change, this simply prevents that.

Comment: Just so you know, it took my bot 63 minutes to count 45,182 of my messages in 91 channels, 74 of which are text channels